# PHP : How to print each array value on table

Tags: php, arrays

So I try to retrieve all data from user table and put it on Array.

This is the Array output :

```
Array ( [error] => false 
  [users] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
      [user_id] => 34
      [name] => test1
      [status] => actived ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
      [user_id] => 35
      [name] => test2
      [status] => actived ) 
  )
)
```

And this my table code in HTML :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th class="numeric">ID</th>
      <th class="numeric">Name</th>
      <th class="numeric">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="numeric"><?php ID VALUE HERE ?></td>
      <td class="numeric"><?php NAME VALUE HERE ?></td>
      <td class="numeric"><?php STATUS VALUE HERE ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I already try foreach like this :

```
foreach ($error as $key => $val) {

}
```

and put the `print_r ($val[0]['name']);` into the NAME VALUE.
but it just make the table is worst.

How to put each array value into that table ?

What is the best way to do that ?
Thanks :)

Comment: I think a foreach loop is the way to go

Comment: already solved thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
 $arr = Array ( [error] => false 
                [users] => Array ( 
                      [0] => Array ( 
                                    [user_id] => 34
                                    [name] => test1
                                    [status] => actived ) 
                      [1] => Array ( 
                                    [user_id] => 35
                                    [name] => test2
                                    [status] => actived ) 
                    ) 
              );

 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
     <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Code</th>
           <th>Company</th>
           <th class="numeric">ID</th>
           <th class="numeric">Name</th>
           <th class="numeric">Status</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <?php foreach($arr['users'] as $user): ?>
         <tr>
           <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['user_id'] ?></td>
           <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['name'] ?></td>
           <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['status'] ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

this will give you the exact output.

Answer (score 1):

## [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Try this: assuming variable name variable

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
<?php
foreach($variable['users'] as $user)
{ ?>
  <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['user_id'] ?></td>
      <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['name'] ?></td>
      <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['status'] ?></td
<?php }?>
</tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = Array ( [error] => false 
    [users] => Array ( 
                      [0] => Array ( 
                                    [user_id] => 34
                                    [name] => test1
                                    [status] => actived ) 
                      [1] => Array ( 
                                    [user_id] => 35
                                    [name] => test2
                                    [status] => actived ) 
                    ) );


<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
     <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Code</th>
           <th>Company</th>
           <th class="numeric">ID</th>
           <th class="numeric">Name</th>
           <th class="numeric">Status</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
<?php foreach($data['users'] as $user):?>
         <tr>
           <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['user_id']; ?></td>
           <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['name']; ?></td>
           <td class="numeric"><?php echo $user['status']; ?></td>
          </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th class="numeric">ID</th>
      <th class="numeric">Name</th>
      <th class="numeric">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach($array['user'] as $user) {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="numeric"><?php echo  $user['user_id'] ?></td>
          <td class="numeric"><?php echo  $user['name'] ?></td>
          <td class="numeric"><?php echo  $user['status'] ?></td>
        </tr>   
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php foreach($arrayData['users'] as $data){ ?>
     <td class="numeric"><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th class="numeric">ID</th>
      <th class="numeric">Name</th>
      <th class="numeric">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  foreach($my_array['users'] as $value){
    echo '<tr>'.chr(13);
    echo '  <td class="numeric">'.$value['user_id'].'</td>'.chr(13);
    echo '  <td class="numeric">'.$value['name'].'</td>'.chr(13);
    echo '  <td class="numeric">'.$value['status'].'</td>'.chr(13);
    echo '</tr>'.chr(13);
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```